# Download Tar File via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

I have two nodejs http servers, one requests a tar file from the other. It works fine via browser testing, but I can never get the second server to glue the chunks together correctly.  My attempts with fwrite has been as useless as this

```
// Receives File
var complete_file = '';
response.on('data', function(chunk){
   complete_file += chunk 
}).on('end', function(){
    fs.writeFile('/tmp/test.tgz', complete_file, 'binary')
});

// Send File
fs.readFile('/tmp/test_send.tgz', function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    response.writeHead('200', {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-compressed',
        'Content-Length' : data.length
    });
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to make it work but I use a writeable stream instead, this is the client code:

```
fs = require ('fs');

var http = require('http');
var local = http.createClient(8124, 'localhost');
var request = local.request('GET', '/',{'host': 'localhost'});
request.on('response', function (response) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
    var headers = JSON.stringify(response.headers);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + headers);
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/node/test.gz');
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        file.write(chunk);
        }).on('end', function(){
          file.end();
          });
    });
request.end();
```

Answer (score 7):

This has changed in newer versions of Node.

Here is the latest, and I add more logic to try harder to finish downloading such as encouting 301,302...

```
function getFile(url, path, cb) {
    var http_or_https = http;
    if (/^https:\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/.test(url)) {
        http_or_https = https;
    }
    http_or_https.get(url, function(response) {
        var headers = JSON.stringify(response.headers);
        switch(response.statusCode) {
            case 200:
                var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                response.on('data', function(chunk){
                    file.write(chunk);
                }).on('end', function(){
                    file.end();
                    cb(null);
                });
                break;
            case 301:
            case 302:
            case 303:
            case 307:
                getFile(response.headers.location, path, cb);
                break;
            default:
                cb(new Error('Server responded with status code ' + response.statusCode));
        }

    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        cb(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why the regexp? If it's a real URL, then if it's https it *has* to start with `https://` (that's how protocols have worked since the earliest RFC) so: ```if (url.indexOf("https://") === 0) { http_or_https = https; }```

Answer (score 2):

what about request package?

you can do this:

```
request(fileurl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(savetohere))
```