# How to download a file with Node.js using HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, https

I want to download file from https server using nodejs. I tried this function, but it works only with http:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11700113

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `https` module then. Quoting [**the docs**](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html):

> HTTPS is the HTTP protocol over TLS/SSL. In Node this is implemented
>   as a separate module.

The good news is that the request-related methods of that module (`https.request()`, `https.get()` etc.) support all the options that the ones from `http` do.

Comment: Be sure you use `gzip: true` option if the response is gzipped. I spent almost a day figuring this out. My downloaded files ended up smaller than original and would not open correctly.

Answer (score 21):

Using standard Node modules only:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

/**
 * Downloads file from remote HTTP[S] host and puts its contents to the
 * specified location.
 */
async function download(url, filePath) {
  const proto = !url.charAt(4).localeCompare('s') ? https : http;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    let fileInfo = null;

    const request = proto.get(url, response => {
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        fs.unlink(filePath, () => {
          reject(new Error(`Failed to get '${url}' (${response.statusCode})`));
        });
        return;
      }

      fileInfo = {
        mime: response.headers['content-type'],
        size: parseInt(response.headers['content-length'], 10),
      };

      response.pipe(file);
    });

    // The destination stream is ended by the time it's called
    file.on('finish', () => resolve(fileInfo));

    request.on('error', err => {
      fs.unlink(filePath, () => reject(err));
    });

    file.on('error', err => {
      fs.unlink(filePath, () => reject(err));
    });

    request.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to check the statusCode if you already have an `on` `error`handler? And why do you unlink the file only in the error handler and not in case of `statusCode !== 200`?

Comment: @Toxiro, yes, you do need to check statusCode since it's an HTTP error, not a data transfer error. But you're right, the file should be unlinked in case of `statuseCode !== 200` too. Updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple:

```js
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

/**
 * Download a file to disk
 * @example downloadFile('https://orcascan.com', './barcode-tracking.html')
 * @param {string} fileUrl - url of file to download
 * @param {string} destPath - destination path
 * @returns {Promise} resolves once complete, otherwise rejects
 */
function downloadFile(fileUrl, destPath) {

    if (!fileUrl) return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid fileUrl'));
    if (!destPath) return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid destPath'));

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        fetch(fileUrl).then(function(res) {
            var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(destPath);
            res.body.on('error', reject);
            fileStream.on('finish', resolve);
            res.body.pipe(fileStream);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `node-fetch` is now esm only, so I had to swap the requires for import and change my code to a module but this still worked flawlessly!

Comment: `fetch` is now built into Node.js, eliminating the need for `node-fetch`

Comment: Sweet. Which version? Can you provide a revised example?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const request = require('request');
/* Create an empty file where we can save data */
let file = fs.createWriteStream(`file.jpg`);
/* Using Promises so that we can use the ASYNC AWAIT syntax */        
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let stream = request({
        /* Here you should specify the exact link to the file you are trying to download */
        uri: 'https://LINK_TO_THE_FILE',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6,la;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4,de;q=0.3',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
        },
        /* GZIP true for most of the websites now, disable it if you don't need it */
        gzip: true
    })
    .pipe(file)
    .on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`The file is finished downloading.`);
        resolve();
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
    })
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Something happened: ${error}`);
});
```

Comment: build a simple scraper with NodeJs:https://learnscraping.com/4-easy-steps-to-web-scraping-with-nodejs/

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solves the problem, instead of posting code-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24962216)